# CSS: Hover affects other elements instead the hovered one

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

Good day, I have this setup:

```
<div class="container">
    <div class="project">
        <img>
    </div>
    <div class="project">
        <img>
    </div>
    <div class="project">
        <img>
    </div>
...
</div>
```

I have a list of projects and their thumbnails. When a user hovers on one of the projects all the remaining projects' thumbnails must become semi-transparent.

```
.custom_container {
    width: 80%;
    margin: 0 auto;
    text-align: center;
}

.project {
    display: inline-block;
    width: 300px;
    margin: 20px;
    margin-top: 0px;
    margin-bottom: 40px;

    p, h4 {
        text-align: left;
    }

    img {
        width: 100%;
    }

    transition: all 0.2s ease-in-out;
}
```

Comment: Where is your `CSS`?

Comment: @Aaron I think it's CSS3. The CSS file is in the asset pipeline of my Rails App.

Comment: @Aaron my bad. I'm doing it.

Comment: @ValentinGenev no problem, this is why your question has been marked down, by other users.

Comment: @Aaron Thank you, I am beginner and I didn't think it will be relevant.

Comment: @ValentinGenev Thanks, I've added an answer for you below :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Like this?

```
.project img {
    opacity: .5;
}
.project:hover img {
    opacity: 1;
}
```

## EDIT

Based on your comment, you need jQuery for that.

```
$('.project').on('mouseover', function() {
    $(this).siblings().find('img').css('opacity', '.5');
}).on('mouseout', function() {
    $('.project img').css('opacity', '1');        
});
```

[**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/LLppon9h/)

Comment: No. :/ The images shouldn't be transparent all the time, only when one is hovered and the one hovered should be fully opaque.

Comment: Looking it all the answers, which are all practically the same. The problem might be that the question doesn't exactly describe what you want. Next time try to be more specific please.

Answer (score 0):

```
.project > img {
  opacity: 0.4;
  filter: alpha(opacity=40); /* For IE8 and earlier */
}

.project > img:hover{
  opacity: 1;
  filter: alpha(opacity=100); /* For IE8 and earlier */
}
```

Would this CSS work?

http://www.w3schools.com/css/css_image_transparency.asp

Update after clarification:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$('.project > img').on('hover', function(){

  $('.project > img').not(this).css({ opacity: 0.5 });

}, function(){

  $('.project > img').css({ opacity: 1 });

});
</script>
```

Comment: The images shouldn't be transparent all the time, only when one is hovered and the one hovered should be fully opaque.

Comment: @ValentinGenev There are certainly ways to do it with pure CSS, but they wouldn't be very flexible and you'd be constantly working around it. I'd recommend that you use jQuery. I updated my answer with some sample jQuery that should get you started.

Comment: Thank you, Derek, I will try this ASAP.

Answer (score 0):

Going on your comments above this is what you want...

```
.project img {
    opacity: 1;
    transition: all ease .2s;
}
.project:hover img {
    opacity: 0;
}
```

Fiddle here http://jsfiddle.net/1y8e7699/

Comment: Hello thank you for answering, but the images shouldn't be transparent all the time, only when one is hovered and the one hovered should be fully opaque.

Comment: That is what this code does. Sets the opacity to **1** which is solid unless hovered which turns the image to opaque **0**

Comment: Oh, no, mate. That's still not it.

Answer (score 0):

You can achive this by jQuery . Something like this

```
$(".project").hover(
function(){
$( ".project" ).not( this ).css( "opacity", "0.5" );},
function(){
$( ".project" ).css( "opacity", "1" );
});
```